# Installing nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

When I try to install nodemon and run the index.js file afterwards, I get an error "command not fund".

Can anyone help here please?

```
(base) XXX@XXX-MacBook-Air chat_backend % npm install nodemon -g
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: Please update to v 2.2.x

added 120 packages, and audited 120 packages in 5s

11 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
(base) XXX@XXX-MacBook-Air
```

Comment: You should show the command you're trying to run and the exact error message that you're getting.

Comment: don't you need "sudo" in order to install global packages on mac?

Comment: copy and paste the entire error massage too in code formatting

Comment: @Syder no you don't and you **should avoid** using `sudo` for these types of things.

Comment: and when you restart your shell did it work then?

Answer (score 1):

When installing npm package globally on macOS and Linux you need to use sudo. So your command to install nodemon should look like this `sudo npm install nodemon -g`.

If you still can't run nodemon, you can try typing `npx nodemon index.js`.

Comment: you shouldn't use sudo and what is npx?

Comment: Bad advice to use `sudo` - you **should avoid** using `sudo` for installing packages globally - https://dev.to/brylie/don-t-use-sudo-with-npm-install-56p9.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `sudo npm i -g nodemon` to install nodemon globally. However, that is not considered "cool".

Instead, you can install `nodemon` as a dev dependency in your project. Install nodemon in your project with the below command (while you are in your project root folder) -

```
npm i nodemon -save-dev
```

You should now be all set.

Comment: Using `sudo` when installing packages globally has nothing to do with “not being cool”, **it’s a security risk**. You **should instead fix your permission errors and do it the right way** - [npm.js - resolving eaccess permission errors](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally). I don’t get why people are suggesting to use `sudo` when it’s clearly not a permission issue form the logs that OP provided.